# How to get smiles from pubchem CID

Tags: cheminformatics

I have downloaded about 10k compounds of interest from pubchem. Im using pubchempy to get smiles for all those structures . I am able to get smiles for each compound one by one but while fetching two many compounds

from pubchempy import Compound

def get_smiles(cid):

```
smiles = []
mol = Compound.from_cid(cid)
if mol:
    smi = mol.canonical_smiles
    #smiles.append(smi)
    return smi
else:
    return None
```

i get error

''return opener.open(url, data, timeout)'' and

<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

how can i get rid of this error

Comment: python.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR: Assuming you still are connected to NIH, *possibly* a constrain by the database's rules of access.

I don't understand much why you want to re-define the generation of [`pubchempy`](https://github.com/mcs07/PubChemPy)'s report of SMILES (which needn't be [canonical](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/SMILES_format.html) ones). For example,

```python
import pubchempy as pcp
c = pcp.Compound.from_cid(5090)
print(c.isomeric_smiles)
```

yields `CS(=O)(=O)C1=CC=C(C=C1)C2=C(C(=O)OC2)C3=CC=CC=C3` (condensed from the [documentation](https://pubchempy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guie/gettingstarted.html)) works well (just checked with Python 3.9.8).  Of course the above may be extended to query lists of compounds, too.  Not for beauty, e.g.

```python
import pubchempy as pcp
compounds = [5090, 5091, 5092]
for entry in compounds:
    c = pcp.Compound.from_cid(entry)
    print(c.isomeric_smiles)
```

reports

```
CS(=O)(=O)C1=CC=C(C=C1)C2=C(C(=O)OC2)C3=CC=CC=C3
CCCC(=O)OC1C(OC(CC1(C)OC(=O)CC)OC2C(OC(C(C2N(C)C)O)OC3C(CC(C(C=CC=CCC(OC(=O)CC(C3OC)O)C)O)C)CC=O)C)C
COC1=C(C=C(C=C1)C2CC(=O)NC2)OC3CCCC3
```

However, `pubchempy` has to follow NIH's rules of access like any other mode of access, i.e.

> - No more than 5 requests per second.
> - No more than 400 requests per minute.
> - No longer than 300 second running time per minute.
>
> NIH's documentation, [programmatic access](https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/programmatic-access)

regardless if using NIH's [PUG](https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug-rest-tutorial) (with time out after $\pu{30 s}$ server time, [ref](https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/programmatic-access)), or an interface like `pubchempy` which recommends e.g., [grouping](https://pubchempy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/advanced.html) the requests in smaller portions as strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the Clarification it helped me a lot!